# $\int \frac{q}{\sqrt[3]{k^3-q^3+\frac{3 }{8}q^2}} \, dq$ where $k = 0.14$

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{q}{\sqrt[3]{k^3-q^3+\frac{3 }{8}q^2}} \, dq$$

I have tried solve this by substituting $k^3-q^3+\frac{3}{8}q^2 = u$ but this wont work because of the higher order polynomials it has. tried to factorize it but not still smooth for me to work with. Please, i really need help to go about this.

Thanks George

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to format the expression of the integral by following this explanations: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28q%2F%281.4%5E3-q%5E3%2B%283%2F8%29*q%5E2%29%5E%281%2F3%29%2C+q%29) fails at this. Are you sure there is a closed-form answer?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{q}{\sqrt[3]{k^3-q^3+\frac{3 }{8}q^2}} \, dq$$ 
First, solve for $r$ the equation :
$$k^3-r^3+\frac{3 }{8}r^2=0$$
The three roots (real and complex) are : $r_1$ , $r_2$ and $r_3$.

The integral can be written on the form :
$$\int \frac{q}{\sqrt[3]{(q-r_1)(q-r_2)(q-r_3)}} \, dq$$
On this form, the integral is known to be related with the Appell's hypergeometric functions.

So, the result can be expressed on a closed form, thanks to the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

If you are familiar with this kind of special function, in order to be able to use it for further calculus, I could give you the explicit formula which is not simple. If not, better use numerical integration.